# auto-complete for two text fields jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have following jquery mobile script for providing auto-complete feature for two text fields `customer` and `store`.

```
$(function() {
    $("#customer").keyup(function(event) {
            if(document.getElementById("customer").value == "")
                $( "#store" ).prop( 'disabled', true );
    });

    $('#customer').autocomplete({
        source: "./SearchCustomer.php?term="+document.getElementById("customer").value,
        minLength: 0,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#customer" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $( "#customer" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#customer-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
            $("#store").removeAttr("disabled").focus();
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      $(ul).attr('data-role', 'listview');
      $(ul).listview();
      return $( "<li>" ).append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
    };

    $('#store').autocomplete({
        source: "./SearchStore.php?customer="+document.getElementById("customer").value+"&searchText="+document.getElementById("store").value,
        minLength: 0,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#store" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $( "#store" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#store-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" ).append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
    };

});
```

Here is html:

```
<label for="name">Customer:</label>
<input type="text" name="customer" id="customer" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="customer-id" />
<p id="customer-description"></p>

<label for="name">Store:</label>
<input type="text" name="store" id="store" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="store-id" />
<p id="store-description"></p>
```

The auto-complete feature for customer text box is working but not for store text field.
I replicated the same `customer` auto-complete code in store autocomplete and i am sure that data is returning from SearchStore.php .

Any suggestions to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can u debug if you are getting the value for store text field again and confirm?

Comment: Pls Provide your html

Comment: @sangramparmar HTML added above.

Comment: why are you using .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

Comment: I found this code from another thread. I debugged my code and found out that customer field is getting empty before calling to SearchStore.php

Comment: It seems that only first auto-complete function executes and after that no other auto-complete do their job. Can anyone point out the issue?

Comment: can u try with document ready. I know $(function() and doc ready are almost same but still. could you give it a try

Comment: I tried but same result. This is killing me. If I put Store autocomplete before customer then store works only. Only the first one is working :'(

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below code:

```
 $(function() {
    $("#customer").keyup(function(event) {
            if(document.getElementById("customer").value == "")
                $( "#store" ).prop( 'disabled', true );
    });

    $('#customer').autocomplete({
        source: "./SearchCustomer.php?term="+document.getElementById("customer").value,
        minLength: 0,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#customer" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $( "#customer" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#customer-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
            $("#store").removeAttr("disabled").focus();
            return false;
        }
    })

.each(function() {
    $(this).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      $(ul).attr('data-role', 'listview');
      $(ul).listview();
      return $( "<li>" ).append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
    };
    }

    $('#store').autocomplete({
        source: "./SearchStore.php?customer="+document.getElementById("customer").value+"&searchText="+document.getElementById("store").value,
        minLength: 0,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#store" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $( "#store" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#store-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
            return false;
        }
    })
.each(function() {
    $(this).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" ).append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
    };
    }

});
```

Comment: what console pops up?